# Does Swagger 2.0 support matrix parameters?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Does Swagger 2.0 support matrix parameters of JAX-RS specification?

[JAX-RS specification](https://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/sources/spec/content/spec.pdf) have [Matrix-Parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/MatrixParam.html) support.

I have some matrix parameter present in my application such as `/map/color;lat=50;long=20;scale=32000`. 
I want to derive Swagger for matrix parameters. I use http://editor.swagger.io; but I could not got any help in the editor. Can anyone help me?

Does Swagger 2.0 support matrix parameters?

Other links ralted to matrix param:

- https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html
- https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/restful-java-with/9780596809300/ch05s03.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Swagger 2.0 spec](http://swagger.io/specification/) does not mention anything about JAX-RS Matrix parameter.

Also looking at the swagger-jaxrs implementation, you can see that `@MatrixParam` is ignored in [the class](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jaxrs/DefaultParameterExtension.java#L39) responsible for scanning JAX-RS parameter annotations.

Comment: There is a proposal in the next version to support them.  Not sure if it'll happen, but you can follow it if you like:  https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/69

Comment: `@MatrixParam` is now supported in swagger-core 2.0 and corresponds to OpenAPI 3.0's `style: matrix`.

Answer (score 3):

OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 does not support matrix parameters, but they are supported in OpenAPI 3.x.

Using OpenAPI 3, your example:

```
/map/color;lat=50;long=20;scale=32000
```

can be defined as:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
...
paths:
  /map/color{params}:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: params
          required: true
  
          # Named matrix parameters are defined as object properties
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              lat:
                type: integer
                example: 50
              long:
                type: integer
                example: 20
              scale:
                type: integer
                example: 32000
  
          # Serialize this object as ;prop1=value2;prop2=value2 etc
          style: matrix
          explode: true
```

#### Swagger UI/Editor Support

This is supported in Swagger UI 3.15.0+ and Swagger Editor 3.5.6+. In the parameter editor, enter the parameter names and values in the JSON object format, e.g.:

```json
{
  "lat": 50,
  "long": 20,
  "scale": 32000
}
```

"Try it out" will send these parameters as matrix parameters in the URL:

[image: Matrix parameters in Swagger UI]

#### Swagger-Core Support

For those using Java annotations, `@MatrixParam` is supported in swagger-core 2.0. `@MatrixParam` corresponds to OpenAPI 3's path parameters with `style: matrix` (as in the example above).